# Enqueueing jQuery plugin in Wordpress theme template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, enqueue

I made a template called test-stuff.php and tried using jQuery and the jQuery validation plugin in it. I've enqueued the scripts in my functions.php file and the jQuery works fine on other regular pages, but not in my template.
Could someone point out where I went wrong? Do I have to enqueue jquery and the jquery plugin separetely for the template? If I have left out some details, please ask and I will provide. Thanks in advance.

functions.php enqueuing part:

```
function my_custom_queue() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'validatejq', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_queue' );
```

Template file with jquery testing function(I get "no"):

```
<?php 

/* Template name: Test stuff */

?>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    /* test */
    if (window.jQuery) {
        alert("Yes");
    } else {
        alert("No");
    }
};

</script>
```

Comment: You did not include `get_header()` and `get_footer()` in your template, so the scripts are never included. Or is that one of the details you left out?

Comment: Yes that was the issue, thank you for responding so quickly. Sorry about the weirdly easy problem.

Comment: No problem @Zae, happy to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you don't need to enqueue, it is already enqueue by WordPress. Check some of the already included JS libraries. You have not called `get_header()` and `get_footer()` either.

You can check out the following link to get the list of already include libraries.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `get_header()` in your page template in order get the header code (including the enqueued scripts) in your page. And you probably want to use `get_footer()` too. Some scripts are included in the footer.